# Octave quantile and percentile

Tags: octave, percentile, quantile

for some reason i cannot make octave return quantiles. Example:

```
a = 1:15;
quantile(a)
ans= 1 2 3 4 5 6 ... 15
```

While i would expect something like:

```
ans= 1.0  4.5  8.0 11.5 15.0
```

The same happens if i try prctile(a). So, what is the problem?
Regards, Helbo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Octave was trying to calculate the values for each column. Because your input is a row vector, each column has only 1 element, hence the weird behaviour. You can work around this by specifying the dimension (third input argument), or passing the a column vector (use `x(:)`).

Apparently this was Matlab old behaviour but this has since changed, and Octave will now use the first non-singleton dimension (see [bug #40736](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?40736)). If you're using the development version (not yet released) that will work fine:

```
quantile (1:15)
ans =

    1.0000    4.2500    8.0000   11.7500   15.0000
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a = (1:15)';
quantile(a)
ans =

    1.0000
    4.2500
    8.0000
   11.7500
   15.0000
```